# Writing a function with parameter that can be used as an object property

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
interface item {
  first: string;
  last: string;
}

const arr = item[];

myfunc = (index, attributeToChange) => {
  arr[index].attributeToChange = "New first/last"
}
```

In the above code I have array called `arr` that holds objects of type `item`. I'm trying to write a function that takes an array index and a string `attributeToChange` which could be either `first` or `last`.

But if I write my function the way I did above it (obviously) throws a Property 'attributeToChange' does not exist on type 'item' error in TypeScript.

What is the ideal way of writing a function like this?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to look up the property at the value of `attributeToChange` just like `index`:

```
arr[index][attributeToChange] = "New first/last"
```

You'll also want to move the type annotation to the left-hand side:

```
const arr: item[] = [];
```

**Edit**: Based on your comment saying that the TypeScript compiler told you `[ts] Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'item' has no index signature.`, you'll need to add an index signature to the interface. By specifying what key types and value types are in `item`, it won't warn you about having any type.

```
interface item {
  [key: string]: string;
  first: string;
  last: string;
}
```

Comment: problem is, the object i'm dealing with has a lot more properties than just two in this example.

Comment: Ah, then we can remove that note then. :)

Comment: doing `arr[index][attributeToChange]` throws this error: `[ts] Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'item' has no index signature.`

Comment: That error sounds like a problem with your type declaration for arr, not a problem with the function definition.

Comment: Add to the interface: `interface item { [key:string] : string, ... `. https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/index-signatures.html